# Dynamic button creation in a relativelayout for phone and tablet

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, dynamic

I am dynamically creating buttons based on a users interaction with my app. Each time the user does some action with my app, my app received an image, it then uses the image to create an ImageButton. The button is then created and added to a relative layout "home_fragment".

**Each time a button is created I want the layout to follow the image below, where on a phone the buttons line up to create two rows, and on a tablet they line up to create 3 rows,** but each button will be added one at a time, so row1column1 first, then row2column2, then (for the phone) row1column2 and (for the tablet) row3column1), etc.

[image]

Right now I just have buttons created dynamically and added to an empty relativelayout with a horizonalScrollView on the phone and tablet and each time a button is created it pops up on top of the previously created button.

```
ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
                       //btn.setId(1);
                       btn.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
                       Log.d("tag_name", "Create Button" + btn);

                       ViewGroup RelativeLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.home_fragment);
                       btn.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                       RelativeLayout.addView(btn);
                       Log.d("tag_name", "Button Added to View" + RelativeLayout);
```

**Does anyone know THE BEST WAY I can go about getting my buttons to add to my view like the image I want?** Can I create a table of some sort for my phone and tablet and just have the empty spaces get filled in with buttons?

Comment: Have you considered a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`? You can use an integer resource and overload it in configurations with large screens to determine the number of rows/columns.

Comment: @Karakuri Thank you for the idea. I have looked a little into this and I was wondering if I use this approach, do I have to predefine how many buttons I will have in the layout? Because I need the number to be dynamic based on my user's actions. Some users might create three buttons, others might create 20. Would this approach work for that?

Comment: `RecyclerView` uses an `Adapter`. The adapter reports how many items it has and how to represent an item as a View (or a hierarchy of Views). If you have for example a `List` of user actions, your adapter could report `list.size()` for the number of items and `RecyclerView` will react accordingly.

Comment: @Karakuri can you take a look at another question I posted about issues I am having with this method? Thanks! Maybe this method can't be used for dynamic buttons? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170063/dynamic-buttons-added-to-a-gridlayout-using-recyclerview-are-added-on-top-of-eac