# Dynamic buttons added to a GridLayout using RecyclerView are added on top of each other

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-recyclerview, grid-layout

I want to add dynamic buttons to a grid layout as shown below. **Each button is added one at a time**, and the layout must update itself to have the buttons in rows. **My problem is that when a new button is added it appears on top of the last button added, and is not placed in a row format.** In this image below I show what I want and what is currently happening, where the squares labeled with numbers are my buttons. In the image of what I have, I have added 6 buttons to the layout, but they are all on top of each other.

[image]

I have looked around about how to do this, and it was recommended to me that I use a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`. I have added this to my code, but like I said **the problem is that when I add a button, and then if I add another button, the second one is added on top of the first.** What I have works if my buttons are preset, but not for dynamic buttons.

Here is my code:

Main Fragment initiates the `RecyclerView`. I have another activity that initiates `createButton()` method and passes a *drawable* and *String*. These drawables and strings are passed to this method one at a time based on the user's action, and create an image button one at a time.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private GridLayoutManager lLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    // onCreateView
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

        // Get screen size to have different layouts for phone and tablet
        int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

        String toastMsg;
        switch (screenSize) {
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
                toastMsg = "Large screen";
                Log.d("tag_name", "Large screen");
                break;
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
                toastMsg = "Normal screen";
                Log.d("tag_name", "Normal screen");
                break;
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
                toastMsg = "Small screen";
                Log.d("tag_name", "Small screen");
                break;
            default:
                toastMsg = "Screen size is neither large, normal or small";
                Log.d("tag_name", "Screen size is not large, normal, or small");
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Create an empty list to initialize the adapter (or else get nullPointerException error)
        List<ItemObject> myList = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();

        // 3 rows for tablet
        // 2 rows for phone

        if (screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE
                || screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
            lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        } else
            lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

        RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

        RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), myList);
        rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(String applicationName, Drawable app_drawable) {

        List<ItemObject> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
        allItems.add(new ItemObject(applicationName, app_drawable));

        return allItems;
    }

    public void createButton(Drawable d, String appName) {

        List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList(appName, d);
        lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);


        RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

        RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), rowListItem);
        rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);

    }

}
```

My layout (my_fragment):

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/new_app_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/new_app_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/new_app_button"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**

**HERE IS MY UPDATED CODE FOR MyFragment** 
Now I am getting a nullPointerException when the second ImageButton gets added

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private GridLayoutManager lLayout;

private ButtonCreator bc;
RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    List<ItemObject> myList = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
    rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),myList);

}

// onCreateView
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);


    // Get screen size so we can have different layouts for phone and tablet
    int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

    String toastMsg;
    switch(screenSize) {
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
            toastMsg = "Large screen";
            Log.d("tag_name", "Large screen");
            break;
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
            toastMsg = "Normal screen";
            Log.d("tag_name", "Normal screen");
            break;
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
            toastMsg = "Small screen";
            Log.d("tag_name", "Small screen");
            break;
        default:
            toastMsg = "Screen size is neither large, normal or small";
            Log.d("tag_name", "Screen size is not large, normal, or small");
    }
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    // Create an empty list to initialize the adapter (or else get nullPointerException error)

    if (screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE
    || screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
        lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    }

    else lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);


    RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);


    rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);


    return view;
}

private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(String applicationName, Drawable app_drawable){

    List<ItemObject> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
    allItems.add(new ItemObject(applicationName, app_drawable));


    return allItems;
}


public void createButton (Drawable d, String appName){

    rcAdapter.addItem(new ItemObject(appName , d));

}



// In order to get the view of HomeFragment correctly

public interface ButtonCreator{
    void buttonCreator(Drawable d, String string);
}



@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    bc = (ButtonCreator) activity;
}

}
```

**How I am calling createButton method in MyFragment (called in the runOnUiThread method)**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MyFragment.ButtonCreator {


private Thread repeatTaskThread;
private byte[] byteArray;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

   FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.replace(R.id.container, new MyFragment()).commit();
}


public void buttonCreator(Drawable d,String a) {
    MyFragment homeFragment = (MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1);
    homeFragment.createButton(d, a);
}

public void RepeatTask(){

     repeatTaskThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
           while (true) {


              try {


                 System.out.println("TRY_1");

                 Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.26", 5050);

                 // Get data sent through socket
                 DataInputStream DIS = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                 System.out.println("DataInputStream Started");

                 // read data that got sent
                 final String applicationName = DIS.readUTF();


                 // read array data for bitmap

                 int len = DIS.readInt();
                 byte[] data = new byte[len];

                 DIS.readFully(data, 0, data.length);


                 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                 final Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);


                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                       Log.d("tag_name", "Try_2");

                        buttonCreator(d,applicationName);


                    }
                 });


                 socket.close();




              } catch (Exception e) {


                 System.out.println("Exception is " + e.toString());

              }


              try {
                 // Sleep for 5 seconds
                 Thread.sleep(5000);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
           }
        }

        ;
     };
     repeatTaskThread.start();


}

}
```

MY error when my app crashes on the second button creation:

```
05-11 17:05:25.275 14257-14257/it.anddev.bradipao.janus E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
05-11 17:05:25.275 14257-14257/it.anddev.bradipao.janus D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-11 17:05:25.275 14257-14257/it.anddev.bradipao.janus W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x437c0160)
05-11 17:05:25.305 14257-14257/it.anddev.bradipao.janus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: it.anddev.bradipao.janus, PID: 14257
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollRange(RecyclerView.java:1518)
                                                                          at android.view.View.onDrawScrollBars(View.java:12248)
                                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14794)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:3171)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13655)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13697)
                                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14505)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3134)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2971)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13650)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13697)
                                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14505)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3134)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild(RecyclerView.java:3693)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2971)
                                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14791)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:3171)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13655)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13697)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3108)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13593)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13697)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3108)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13593)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13697)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3108)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13593)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13697)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3108)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13593)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13697)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3108)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13593)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13697)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3108)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13593)
                                                                          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13697)
                                                                          at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1570)
                                                                          at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2476)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2300)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1929)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1043)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:771)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:757)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I see that every time you need t create a button you are reinitializing the recyclerView, the result is that a new recyclerView is created with that button .

Comment: @varunkr I see! So I guess I am initializing the recyclerView each time in my createButton method of MyFragment right? So do you know how I can change this code to update, instead of creating a new recyclerView each time?

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private GridLayoutManager lLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    // onCreateView
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

        // Get screen size to have different layouts for phone and tablet
        int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

        String toastMsg;
        switch (screenSize) {
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
                toastMsg = "Large screen";
                Log.d("tag_name", "Large screen");
                break;
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
                toastMsg = "Normal screen";
                Log.d("tag_name", "Normal screen");
                break;
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
                toastMsg = "Small screen";
                Log.d("tag_name", "Small screen");
                break;
            default:
                toastMsg = "Screen size is neither large, normal or small";
                Log.d("tag_name", "Screen size is not large, normal, or small");
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Create an empty list to initialize the adapter (or else get nullPointerException error)

        // 3 rows for tablet
        // 2 rows for phone

        if (screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE
                || screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
            lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        } else
            lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

        RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

        rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter;

    private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(String applicationName, Drawable app_drawable) {

        List<ItemObject> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
        allItems.add(new ItemObject(applicationName, app_drawable));

        return allItems;
    }

    public void createButton(Drawable d, String appName) {

        rcAdapter.addItem(new ItemObject(appName , d))

    }

}
```

And in the adapter add this method

```
public void addItem(int position) {
        list.add(position);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());
    }
```

**EDIT**

To prevent the warning try moving your adapter initialization to onCreate

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            List<ItemObject> myList = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
            rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), myList);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! for my addItem I had to use this code: "public void addItem(ItemObject item) {
    mList.add(item);
    notifyItemInserted(mList.size() - 1);
}"            So that I wouldn't get errors, and can build my gradle. When I get my first image for my image button I get the warning "No adapter attached: skipping layout", but my image button gets created fine. But then when I try to add a second image button to the layout I get the same warning and also my app crashes giving a nullPointerException. Is there any obvious thing you can see that causes this?

Comment: @Natalie Can you quote the exact null pointer exception that u get

Comment: It doesn't get rid of the error if I add my adapter initialization to onCreate, but I did update my question to show the error. I will have to try and figure out what is throwing the "null" because my stackTrace isn't telling me much right now.

Comment: @Natalie How exactly are you calling this createButton method from the activity? The difference between what you did earlier and what u r doing now is that now your create button doesn't initialize the recyclerView and adapter as it was doing earlier. You might be getting exception due to this, as your adapter etc might remain uninitialized the second time. It depends on how you are starting your fragment and how you call this createButton from your activity. Can you post the activity code. That might solve the issue !!

Comment: I updated my "EDIT" section of my question to show how I am starting my fragment. I am not calling it the same way here as I am in the other question that I posted because that led to nullPointerExceptions when the first image button was created, and now it is happening on the second image button, but perhaps it all stems from the same problem of me initializing my fragments incorrectly?

Comment: @Natalie Your activity code looks perfect, but I think I found the cause. Try removing android:scrollbars="horizontal" from the recyclerView once !!  99% sure that will solve it !!

Comment: Well my second image still does not pop up in the row layout, and I still get the warning "No adapter attached; skipping layout", but that did keep it from crashing! And fixed the NullPointerException!!

Comment: @Natalie That is some progress. I think you can try it and with a little bit of debugging you can solve it. Hard for me to identify the issue by simply looking at the code. The error No adapter attached looks like a general one, you can search for it.  About the second image button. Try putting a log inside createButton to see if it is being called or not.

Comment: Thank you for all the help!

Comment: @Natalie Thnx for accepting the answer, I am sorry I couldn't solve the original problem. Just one final input I would like to give. Since you were earlier able to put the images over and over again, it means thatcreateButton is called. So you should just try to fix the error No adapter attached, skipping layout. That might fix it, if it still doesn't after fixing that errror, try posting a new question. Good liuck !!

Answer (score 1):

When you create a button, you should only have to do two things:

1. Update the data structure that is backing the `RecyclerView`
   adapter
2. Notify the adapter that the data has changed using one of the `notify...()` methods of the adapter (there are [several of them](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()), use the most applicable one)

Your current code does not appear to do either of these things. You also do not need to create or set any new adapters or layout managers.

In your case, you would be adding an element to the list held by your adapter class and then probably call [`notifyItemInserted()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int)) with an appropriate position. You could do both at once by adding a method to your adapter:

```
public void addItem(ItemObject item) {
    mList.add(item);
    notifyItemInserted(mList.size() - 1);
}
```

---

Unrelated: On Android you can use the resource resolution system to determine the number of columns to show.

Make `src/main/res/values/integers.xml` and add:

```
<resources>
    <integer name="grid_column_count">2</integer>
</resources>
```

Make `src/main/res/values-large/integers.xml` and add:

```
<resources>
    <integer name="grid_column_count">3</integer>
</resources>
```

Notice the **`-large`**, which will inform the system that screens of this size and above should use this alternate resource value. Now in your Fragment you can simply write:

```
int columnCount = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.grid_column_count);
GridLayoutManager layout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), columnCount, 
        GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

I mention this because screen size bucket (the `-large`) may not be the best way to determine the number of columns. You might be better suited using a screen width qualifier instead (such as `-w600dp`), which will be updated if the device rotates (whereas the size bucket does not change in that scenario). You can read more about resource qualifiers [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Comment: Thanks! In regards to updating my adapter: When I get my first image for my image button I get the warning "No adapter attached: skipping layout", but my image button gets created fine. But then when I try to add a second image button to the layout I get the same warning and also my app crashes giving a nullPointerException. Is there any obvious thing you can see that causes this?

Comment: @Natalie It's better to post a separate question including the entire stack trace from Logcat, if you can't solve it yourself first

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion for how to get my screen size. Your solution is so much more elegant.